# AWS Lambda Edit Code Inline shows "Loading your function..." continuously

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Edit Code Inline shows "Loading your function..." continuously and never actually loads the function.

And since function does not load, you obviously can not edit it.

I think there was some kind of update today (Nov 30, 2017) to Lambda because when you click on a function to edit it, there is a new section at the top that shows CONFIGURATION and says ADD TRIGGER which was not there yesterday.

And when you scroll down to the Function Code section, it just says "Loading your function..." and never does anything else.

Anybody else seeing this odd behavior?

EDIT: Using Firefox 57 on Windows 10. I get the following warnings/errors when I check Firefox console:

WARNINGS:

window.controllers/Controllers is deprecated. Do not use it for UA detection.  ace.js:1:18479

Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. globalnav-fe3b9e5995ba8d342d395cb57493ce54ac2b40bb.gz.js:2:39229

window.controllers/Controllers is deprecated. Do not use it for UA detection. environment-default.js:5987

The ‘content’ attribute of Window objects is deprecated.  Please use ‘window.top’ instead. home

ERRORS:

Unhandled promise rejection 
DOMException {  }
polyfill.js:4326:11
onUnhandled/https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:4326:11
[90]https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:1786:27
onUnhandled/<
https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:4320:16
[46]https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:993:25

https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:2154:7
run
https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:2140:5
listener
https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:2144:3

Unhandled promise rejection 
DOMException {  }
polyfill.js:4326:11
onUnhandled/https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:4326:11
[90]https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:1786:27
onUnhandled/<
https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:4320:16
[46]https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:993:25

https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:2154:7
run
https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:2140:5
listener
https://d3ifj4k507k5fs.cloudfront.net/ide-164cb54be56918ce7c55af08ee13c6339e8ebc5c/polyfill.js:2144:3

Comment: Looks like AWS deployed updates to the Lambda console. I see them and it works fine here. Make sure that you force reload the browser window in case you have incompatible JavaScript.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for confirming you see updates to Lambda console :) Forcing reload (CTRL+F5) does not solve my problem though :(

Comment: Actually, it looks like an entirely new full-on code editor. Wow, it's nice. Its the ACE editor from https://ace.c9.io/. Maybe some teething troubles?

Comment: Yes, I'm, having the same problem. I've tried different browsers and reloading. It's clearly a bug in their service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What browser do you use? Chrome 62 and Firefox 57 fail at inline editing lambdas and both throw DOMExceptions, but Safari 11 seems to work. Try Safari(or some other browser) for editing while waiting for Amazon to fix this.

Comment: I am using FIrefox 57 which gives me the problem.

Comment: @jsherk Firefox 57 works fine for me here (as well as Chrome 62).

Comment: Not loading on Firefox 52 or Chrome 62 but works fine on IE11 and MS Edge.

Answer (score 84):

I was facing the same issue on Chrome 63.
What worked for me:

- Right Click on the *"Loading your function..."*
- Click on Reload Frame.

It should load the IDE.

[image]

Comment: Worked instantly! Thank you!

Comment: This should be marked as Answer. I am using Chrome 63 and it suddenly stopped loading code. The method worked for me immediately.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: AWS, puh-leeeez son.

Comment: Amazing! I'll have to remember that for lots of other things too :)

Comment: If you see me, beers will be my treat!

Comment: Glad it worked for all of you! surprisingly, It's been over 2 months and Lambda team haven't fixed it yet.

Comment: seems like they are using Cloud 9 IDE for this now.

Comment: This didn't work today (Aug 2020), but switching to Safari worked

Answer (score 5):

This is happening in chrome as chrome is disabling the use of cookies from cloudfront domain.

1. Go to address bar and there you would see a icon that says there are some cookies blocked on this website.
2. Click on it.
3. Click on manage.
4. Click on Blocked.
5. Click on allow to couldfront domain.
6. Reload page.

I have tried it and it's working for me.

Edit: This could also be tried on other browsers that are facing this issue.

Comment: Specifically for Chrome: add [*.]cloudfront.net to the third-party cookie "Allow" list in chrome://settings/content/cookies

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me using the 64-bit version of Google Chrome 75.0.3770.142 on Windows 10 circa July 31st 2019. To resolve, I trashed all browser data e.g., cookies, etc. Steps to remove that data can be found [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392709?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Things that **did not** work for me...

1. Refresh frame.
2. Refresh tab.
3. Close and re-open browser.
4. Restart computer.
5. Cry quietly to myself and question my decisions in life.

The Lambda editor in the console is AWS Cloud9, which needs some stuff (e.g., cookies) that is spelled out [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html).

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me.

Try clearing all aws cookies. That did work.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was FireFox's content blocking causing the problem - click the shield next to "HTTPS Secure" lock on the left hand end of the address bar and click "Turn off blocking for this site".

> Request to access cookie or storage on “https://….cloudfront.net/ide-…/modules/@c9/ide/plugins/c9.ide.language.core/worker.js” was blocked because we are blocking all third-party storage access requests and content blocking is enabled.home

Blocking on (editor not working):
[image: content blocking on]

Blocking off (editor not working):
[image: content blocking off.]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different browser. Worked for me.